# Ignore "unused" warning in Swift when use a "pointer" to func?

Tags: swift, warnings, unused-functions

I know that I should use `@discardableResult`. So I have the following code:

```
@discardableResult func someFunc() { ... }
```

Then I just call it:

```
someFunc()
```

But if I have and use a pointer to this method then it doesn't work again. For example:

```
let someFunc = self.someFunc
someFunc() //unused warning
```

Is it possible to avoid `_=someFunc()` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `discardableResult` only applies to method/function declarations. What you can do is to wrap the value-returning function in a void-returning closure:

```
@discardableResult
func f() -> Int { return 1 }

// the type annotation here is important
let someFunc: () -> Void = { f() }
```

Alternatively, write a function that "erases" the return type of functions:

```
func discardResult<R>(_ f: @escaping () -> R) -> (() -> Void) {
    { _ = f() }
}

let someFunc = discardResult(f)
```

The downside is that you need to write an overload of this for each arity:

```
func discardResult<T, R>(_ f: @escaping (T) -> R) -> ((T) -> Void) {
    { x in _ = f(x) }
}

func discardResult<T, U, R>(_ f: @escaping (T, U) -> R) -> ((T, U) -> Void) {
    { x, y in _ = f(x, y) }
}

func discardResult<T, U, V, R>(_ f: @escaping (T, U, V) -> R) -> ((T, U, V) -> Void) {
    { x, y, z in _ = f(x, y, z) }
}

// and so on
```